# How do Facebook, Google and other large applications do their CSS and JavaScript files?

Tags: javascript, css, facebook, file

Facebook: http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v1/yh/r/u2OL99TwlfU.css

Google: http://ssl.gstatic.com/gb/js/sem_cf9545d69b4bd3d22ed10206010c8b23.js

There are other sites, like Tagged which also uses this kind of method.

How do these sites and other large applications do these files? I assume when they update their file, the URL actually changes so that the cache doesn't recognise the URL and reloads the new file.

I'm actually more confused about Facebook's rsrc.php, but I still don't quite understand the rest. It appears Google's random string is an MD5 of something.

I do want something like this on my websites, large applications use it so it must be useful to use - even if I didn't decide to use, the knowledge of it may be beneficial in the near future.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

(I am the original author of rsrc.php and Facebook's Haste static resource management system.)

You can find a description of some of the challenges Facebook encountered with static resource management and how it solved them here, in the Phabricator documentation:

https://secure.phabricator.com/book/phabflavor/article/soon_static_resources/

To the specific question, the rsrc.php URIs are like that (with "rsrc.php" in them) specifically because we didn't have a global Apache rewrite rule in 2007 when I wrote rsrc.php and adding, deploying and testing one for some more elegant URI didn't seem worth bothering with (in PHP, you can read the remainder of the URI after the "x.php" file part at runtime). So that part is just a PHP implementation artifact.

The other path components have been used for various things over the years, like an emergency version number we can bump globally to break everyone's caches if something goes wrong with the cache pipeline, a hash checksum so we can distinguish between valid and garbage requests for logging, internal flags which alter the cache policy of the returned resource for development, and flavors of a resource (e.g., tailored to a specific browser or localized to a specific language).

Comment: Well, I did assume those random file names - well the Facebook's was a checksum with the original file-name and the last modified date. Though the checksum will need to be reversed in order to get the actual file.

Why I'm asking about this is because I'm wanting to create a similar thing. I do know what effect it has with the Cache. For instance if you had image.png - when that image is updated, you wont' see the change until you hard refresh. There-fore, you need to modify the actual url so that it's unique to that file and last modified date - so you can see updates without hard-refreshing.

Comment: That was an interesting article

Comment: http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net/techblog/article/create_short_ids_with_php_like_youtube_or_tinyurl/ - using this to create a key from an autoincrement id. Along with the auto increment id in the database, you can have a total of all the files (to be combined) last modified timstamp and also a list of files to be combined. When you run the application, it'll build the packages, put together the total of last modified dates and see if it's newer. If it's newer, insert new row and remove the old row. Giving it a new id. I think that's a good start!

Comment: @EvanPriestley how did you guys manage to run bigpipe without coder knowing or doing anything for it. and also how did you guys do bigpipe with no-javascript support. i mean site still runs fine wihtout javascript.. how did you guys code that part in the backend?

Answer (score 0):

Facebook and Google both use a md5 suffix in their static resource file name.

First, it's a general optimization for performance, we can versioning a static resource use the md5 of its file content (after minification) and set the cache-control = 10 years (nginx or apache). If you press forward/back button on your browser or view the page second time, the file will be retrieved from your local disk, not through the network (except you press the reload button, there will be a 304).

Second, when you publish code online, you can first push all static resource, they will not conflict with old ones. And then you push all server-side code, all user will not have error access to your page.